# Why is Bootstrap not working in IE 11 with Compatibility Mode

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

I'm trying to figure out why some of the Bootstrap 3.0 buttons on my site render incorrectly while in "Compatibility Mode" in IE 11.

Here is what it is supposed to look like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7iAy.jpg

This is what it looks like in "Compatibility Mode":

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddynu.jpg

Thanks ahead of time for anyone that knows what causes this. I'm thinking it's a Bootstrap conflict but I'm clueless at this point.

Here is the code:

```
<button id="btnSoftwareDb" class="btn btn-default">
            <div><img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/icon-crm.png")" border="0" alt="Software Database" title="Software Database" class="img-responsive" /></div>
            <div><h5 class="h5">Software<br />Database</h5></div>
        </button>

<button id="btnTDN" class="btn btn-default">
            <div><img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/TDNotebook.png")" border="0" alt="TDNotebook" title="TDNotebook" class="img-responsive" /></div>
            <div><h5 class="h5">TDNotebook<br />Admin</h5></div>
        </button>

<button id="btnDashboard" class="btn btn-default">
            <div><img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/dashboard.png")" border="0" alt="Dashboard" title="Dashboard" class="img-responsive" /></div>
            <div><h5 class="h5">TDNotebook<br />Dashboard</h5></div>
        </button>

<button id="btnMarketing" class="btn btn-default">
            <div><img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/marketing.png")" border="0" alt="Marketing" title="Marketing" class="img-responsive" /></div>
            <div><h5 class="h5">Marketing<br />&nbsp;</h5></div>
        </button>

<button id="btnAdmin" class="btn btn-default">
            <div><img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/knowledgebase.png")" border="0" alt="Admin" title="Admin" class="img-responsive" /></div>
            <div><h5 class="h5">inData<br />Admin</h5></div>
        </button>

<button id="btnProductManagement" class="btn btn-default">
            <div><img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/ProdMgmt.png")" border="0" alt="Admin" title="Admin" class="img-responsive" /></div>
            <div><h5 class="h5">Product<br />Management</h5></div>
        </button>

<button id="btnDevelopment" class="btn btn-default">
            <div><img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/development.png")" border="0" alt="Admin" title="Admin" class="img-responsive" /></div>
            <div><h5 class="h5">Development<br />&nbsp;</h5></div>
        </button>
```